# Gprof granularity

Tags: c, profiling, gprof

This might be a basic question, but I wasn't able to find the answer so far.

I want to determine the ***number*** of calls my program does to a specific function. However, this function is called by another function, which is in turn called by another function, and so on till the point the function I want to determine has probably 5 functions "above it".

How can I determine this with gprof? Currently, it is only showing the top level functions.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using the `-A` option (to generate a source listing annotated with the number of calls per function)?

Comment: Are you compiling *all* the source files with `gcc -pg`? You must use `-pg` for every source you want statistics on, and also for the link.

Comment: Exactly what `gprof` command are you running (i.e. which command-line options)?

Comment: Can you write a wrapper function that only you know the name of, and call that? Also you could have it increment a global counter, so you can print out the number of calls at the end of processing. Just sayin'....

Comment: I couldn't get this to run, other than incrementing a global counter...